# Using form element as variable in Firebase .child()

Tags: javascript, firebase

I would like to use the value of an input from a form element to add a child reference to my firebase data. But, the firebase .child() requires a string, and I've tried to insert a variable (whose value is a string) but it won't work. How do I by pass this?

For example here is a very simple code of an input and submit button. On submission, I want to take the username and add a child reference to my database (under /users ref) in this structure:

{username:{userid: "someID"}}

```
<html>
<body>
<form>
    <input id="testusername" type="text">
    <button type="submit" id="testsubmit" value="submit"></button>
</form>
<p>test file for .child()/p>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $('#testsubmit').on('click',function(){
        var elusername = document.getElementById('testusername');
        var username = elusername.value;
        alert('username is' + username)
        var url = "https://thriftit.firebaseio.com/users";
        var firebaseRef = new Firebase(url);
        firebaseRef.child(username).push({
          userid: "someID"});
    });
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of things.

1. You're submitting the form before the javascript can run, you need to prevent the page from submitting the page on the click, so remove the type="submit"
2. I wouldn't do a child on the username, reason being if another user with the same username adds some data, then it would be added under the same username so you'll get two lots of data under the same username.

You want to so something similar to this:

```
 $('#testsubmit').on('click',function(){
    var elusername = document.getElementById('testusername'),
        username = elusername.value,
        url = "https://thriftit.firebaseio.com/users",
        firebaseRef = new Firebase(url);
        userRef = firebaseRef.push({
            username: username,
            userid: "someID"
        });
    console.log(userRef.name()); // this is the uid for the newly generated user        
});
```

Comment: Frank, thank you for the response. I see your point in #2, and I agree that push() would be better. I'm not sure what you mean in #1. How does my code submit the form before the js is run? Don't I want the function to only carry out after the submit button is pressed?